# Is there a way to solve this differential equation with two functions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, differential

Is there a method to simplify a differential equation with two variables? Specifically I am looking for a way to relate x(t) and y(t) in the following equation and I have a strong urge to say x(t)=y(t) but obviously there are answers where x(t)$\neq$y(t) satisfying the condition. How would you suggest to approach this problem? Or is it impossible to relate x(t) and y(t) simpler than the given equation?

$$\frac{x''(t)}{x(t)} = \frac{y''(t)}{y(t)}$$

note: sorry for the tags, I don't know which category this DE falls into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $y$, we can solve for $x$. Note that writing $f := \frac{y''}y$, the equation reads 
$$ x''(t) = f(t)x(t) $$
Now writet $x = ay$, this gives 
\begin{align*}
  x'' &= a''y + 2a'y' + ay''\\
  fx &= fay\\
 x'' = fx &\iff a''y + 2a'y' + ay'' = fay\\
          &\iff a''y + 2a'y' + ay'' = ay''\\
          &\iff a''y + 2a'y' = 0
\end{align*}
Write $b := a'$, we have 
$$ \frac{b'}b = -2\frac{y'}y $$
or 
$$ \log b(t) = -2 \log y(t) + C $$
for some constant $c$, taking the exponential leaves us with 
$$ b = \frac C{y^2} $$
for (some other) constant $C$. As $a = b'$, we have 
$$ a(t) = C_1 + \int_{t_0}^t \frac{C}{y^2(t)}\, dt $$
or 
$$ x(t) = C_1y(t) + \int_{t_0}^t \frac{C}{y^2(t)}\, dt \cdot y(t) $$
So $x$ and $y$ are related in the above way.

Comment: thanks a lot, I loved the answer